# iOS - if UITextView is editing in if statement

Tags: ios, uitextview, editing

I know that I can check if the `UITextView` is editing using `textViewDidBeginEditing:` but I want to check if it is editing using if statement is there is anyway to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the method `isFirstResponder`, e.g.:

```
if ([myTextView isFirstResponder]){
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov if you mean it doesn't recognize a `UITextView` inside of a `UITableViewCell` that probably true unless you are accessing it from a specific cell itself. Otherwise it is probably `nil` meaning it does nothing.

Comment: it is strange but somehow previously it always returned `YES` but now it works